# Is there a way to iterate over a list of attributes to select in an Ecto query?

Tags: sql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

So, I have a query that I'm trying to construct where there's a list `attributes` which are columns on a table. This query is to group by the list of attributes, count, and return the count with the list of attributes. That last part is what I've had the trouble achieving. Right now I have

```
defmodule ProjectName.Counter do
  import Ecto.Query, only: [group_by: 3, select: 3]

  def group_and_count(queryable, groups) do
    queryable
    |> group_by([q], ^groups)
    |> select([q], count(q.id))
  end
end
```

Which I invoke as such in a context

```
Track
|> Counter.group_and_count([:album, :artist])
|> Repo.all()
```

Which returns me `[1, 5, 4, 2]` which is correct however, not what I'd like it to return. I'd like to actually have the query

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*), tracks.album, tracks.artist FROM tracks GROUP BY tracks.album, tracks.artist
```

which would return

```
[[1, "Calypso", "Harry Belafonte"],
 [5, "Silk & Soul", "Nina Simone"],
 [4, "Hello, Dolly!", "Louis Armstrong"],
 [2, "Pure Gold", "Perry Como"]]
```

How can I change my code to make this work? I can't figure out a way to iterate over `groups` within the `select` query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a much better way of doing it, but it looks like [map/2](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#map/2) and [struct/2](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#struct/2) are made to support passing in lists.

It's ugly, but you could just `select` a tuple containing a map and the count:

```rb
|> select([q], {map(q, ^groups), count(q.id)})
```

Comment: This works pretty perfectly for what I need, so thank you! I wouldn't call it too ugly. It's concise and does the job. ‍♂️